# Can I redefine a variable in Python using function parameters?

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I'm trying to make a function in my program that takes a parameter (string) and deletes punctuation. This is what I have:

```
def massreplace(x):
  global read
  global words
  x = x.replace('\n', '')
  x = x.replace(' ', '')
  x = x.replace('.', '')
  x = x.replace(',', '')
  x = x.replace('!', '')
  x = x.replace('?', '')
```

The parameter will either be the variables read or words. The problem is that I can't assign the variable to the replacement using the parameter. Is there a simple way to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Put `return x` at the end of the function, then when you're calling it do `var = massreplace(var)`

Comment: why are you using `global` variable? Is it necessary. It is not recommended to use `global `variable without usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the external names of our variables don't matter within a function.

So we would do something like:

```
def massreplace(x):
  x = x.replace(' ', '')
  ...
  return x
```

And then we would call our function like:

```
read = massreplace('some words')
words = massreplace('some other words')
```

Does that answer your question, or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the logic of this function and the script itself. For example:

```
def massreplace(x):
    x = x.replace('\n', '')
    x = x.replace(' ', '')
    x = x.replace('.', '')
    x = x.replace(',', '')
    x = x.replace('!', '')
    x = x.replace('?', '')
    return x

if ... :
    replace_var = read
else:
    replace_var = words


replace_var = massreplace(replace_var)
```